# Re-arrange field in JOLT

Tags: json, mapping, transformation, jolt

I am trying to reposition a field called "distributedAmount" in my JOLT output. I want "distributedAmount" after "valid rules" tag.

What I tried- [image]

But the above solution didn't worked. Any idea on what changes I need to make in my spec. d Desired Output- [image]

Input is to long so I have uploaded the input and the jolt spec in Google Drive. Below is the link- https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1vvdFBPwaHRVvjttUTQP0jzQlqYlGfjFZ?usp=share_link

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the line ***402*** to

```json
"@(2,distributedAmount)": "&9.&8.&7.&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.zdistributedAmount"
```

by prepending `distributedAmount` on the right hand side with a **`z`**, and then add the following specs to the current one

```json
  {
    "operation": "sort"
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "*": {
              "*": {
                "*": {
                  "*": {
                    "*": {
                      "*": {
                        "*": {
                          "distributedAmount": "@(1,zdistributedAmount)"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "*": {
              "*": {
                "*": {
                  "*": {
                    "*": {
                      "*": {
                        "*": {
                          "zdistributedAmount": ""
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

where sorting is handled in a bit tricky way by prepending a `z` to the `distributedAmount` key, and renamed back to the original.

Comment: where am I suppose to put this spec? I tried this spec in couple of places but still "distributedAmount" is not coming after "validrules" tag. Like I have shown in the above desired output screenshot.

Comment: Hi @SamJones , I've just fixed by editing due to the missing conversion at the line 402 before.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan, after using this spec my lower part of the code is coming on the header but and vice versa. Any idea on how can I resolve this?